# Changing Order and View of rectangles with Checkbox at same time in javafx?

Tags: javafx

hi i am working with two checkbox in javafx if first one is true then order of rectangles is changed, if second checkbox is true the view should be changed into vertical. here is my example

```
  public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Displaying all the functions in Scene
        StackPane border = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(border, 750, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        HBox h1 = new HBox(20);
        h1.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        HBox h2 = new HBox(20);
        h1.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        VBox p = new VBox(20);

        CheckBox box = new CheckBox("Switch Places");
        CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("Switch");
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(200,200);

        rect1.setFill(null);
        rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200,200);
        rect2.setFill(null);
        rect2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(box,box1);
        h1.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,h2);
        box.setOnAction((e)->{
            if (box.isSelected()){
                h1.getChildren().clear();
                h1.getChildren().addAll(rect2,rect1,h2);
            }
            else if(box.isSelected() && (box1.isSelected())){
                p.getChildren().clear();
                p.getChildren().addAll(rect2,rect1,h2);
                border.getChildren().clear();
                border.getChildren().add(p); 
            }
            else{
                h1.getChildren().clear();
                h1.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,h2);
            }
        });

        box1.setOnAction((e)->{       
            if(box.isSelected() && (box1.isSelected())){
                p.getChildren().clear();
                p.getChildren().addAll(rect2,rect1,h2);
                border.getChildren().clear();
                border.getChildren().add(p); 
            }
            else if(box1.isSelected()){
                p.getChildren().clear();
                p.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,h2);
                border.getChildren().clear();
                border.getChildren().add(p); 
            }
             else{
                    h1.getChildren().clear();
                    h1.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,h2);
                    border.getChildren().clear();
                    border.getChildren().add(h1);
                }   
        });

        border.getChildren().addAll(h1);

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When first checkbox  is true: order of rectangle should be changed

When second checkbox is true: rectangles should be in Vertical view.

When both checkbox are true : order and view both should be changed.

Problem with above code is when second checkbox is true view changed if user click on first check box in this state rectangles disappear! Also how to see only rectangles in vertical view not Checkbox.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the complexity of the code by separating both properties. This way you do not have to consider more than 2 cases when a `CheckBox`'s state is modified.

Simply use 2 `Rectangle`s one of them always is the left/top rect. This allows you to swap the rects by simply replacing the `stroke`s. Also you could modify the layout without the need to take care of the color...

Furthermore you could use a `GridPane` which allows for horizontal AND vertical layout which removes the need to swap the parent of the rects:

```
private static Rectangle createRect(Color stroke) {
    Rectangle result = new Rectangle(200, 200, null);
    result.setStroke(stroke);
    return result;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Displaying all the functions in Scene
    StackPane border = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(border, 750, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    CheckBox orderBox = new CheckBox("Switch Places");
    CheckBox orientationBox = new CheckBox("Switch");
    HBox h2 = new HBox(20, orderBox, orientationBox);

    Rectangle rect1 = createRect(Color.RED);
    Rectangle rect2 = createRect(Color.BLUE);

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    gridPane.setHgap(20);
    gridPane.setVgap(20);
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    // add checkboxes to first row
    gridPane.add(h2, 0, 0, 2, 1);

    // add rects to the second row
    gridPane.addRow(1, rect1, rect2);

    orderBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // assign colors according to order
        if (newValue) {
            rect1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            rect2.setStroke(Color.RED);
        } else {
            rect1.setStroke(Color.RED);
            rect2.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });

    orientationBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // assign locations depending on orientation
        GridPane.setConstraints(rect1, 1, 1);

        if (newValue) {
            GridPane.setConstraints(rect2, 1, 2);
        } else {
            GridPane.setConstraints(rect2, 2, 1);
        }
    });

    border.getChildren().add(gridPane);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `box1` changes scene root to `p`. In `box` handler you add them all to `h1`. JavaFX scene elements can have only one parent. So they are removed from `p` (which is visible at a moment) and added to `h1`, which is not visible.

Comment: What would be the soultion for this?

Comment: @Mudasir add more logic to `box`'s handler. Or better to introduce separate array to store order of your rectangles. So first button will change order of them in this array, second button will change storage between `VBox` and `HBox` and populate them from that array.

Comment: i edited the code above for box's handler, with this user can change the view and order at same time but user cannot undo or unchecked the checkbox to get original position. Sorry i don't have any information on arrays because i am beginner.

Comment: @fabian Thank you so much for help

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.